# App crashes with message "Usage: leveldbutil command..."

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm using Swift 3 and XCode 8.3.3.

My app crashes before starting, it prints :

```
Usage: leveldbutil command...
   dump files...         -- dump contents of specified files
```

Then it crashes I didn't find any solution for this issue.

Comment: Did you try removing the derived data folder for the project?

Comment: Yes i already tried but nothing to do

Comment: What about clean and build?

Comment: Nothing to do... i tried everything but nothing. Luckily i have a copy of my app of 1 week ago, i will re-do some work.

Comment: leveldb as in https://github.com/google/leveldb ? If so, check your usage of this, it's likely unrelated to Xcode or Swift.

Answer (score 1):

check your AppDelegate and find @UIApplicationMain
this statement if this is not available then put in just above the class like this

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project and retry.

[image]